# Setting up dj-stripe (initial migrations) ProgrammingError: relation "djstripe_customer" does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql, stripe-payments

[dj-stripe](https://dj-stripe.readthedocs.org) looks like a very attractive way to manage stripe subscriptions with django.

I installed dj-stripe following the instructions [here](https://dj-stripe.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#get-the-distribution).
Installation seemed to work, in that the installation includes running these three commands, and doing so created and populated new tables in my Postgres DB as well as creating new customer objects in my stripe account.

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py djstripe_init_customers
python manage.py djstripe_init_plans
```

For some reason, I decided dj-stripe was overkill (stripe's api seems easy enough to use without so much boilerplate) so **I uninstalled** using (pip uninstall dj-stripe), removed the mention from INSTALLED_APPS and the entry in urls.py.
To finish the clean-up, I deleted the customers which had been created in my stripe.com account, then I used DROP TABLE to manually delete the leftover tables in my Postgres DB (all tables starting with `djstripe_`: tables like `djstripe_customer`, `djstripe_invoice`, etc.)

Now, I've decided I actually **do want to use dj-stripe**, but this time installation is not working. The second of those three commands throws a `ProgrammingError`

requirements.txt includes:

```
stripe==1.22.3
dj-stripe==0.5.0
```

Installed dj-stripe using pip...

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

...and received success messages.

Then following on instructions as before, I ran into a ProgrammingError.

```
(awe01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$ python manage.py migrate

Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: django_user_agents, evernote, twitter, polls, widget_tweaks, djrill, sitemaps, facebook, django_slack, storages, hello
  Apply all migrations: account, djstripe, admin, sessions, sites, auth, audiotracks, contenttypes, socialaccount
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
  Installing custom SQL...
  Installing indexes...
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

(I'm not sure what the above was supposed to achieve...
At this point I checked my postgres db: **no extra tables have been created**. There is no table with name starting with `djstripe_`)

```
(awe01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$ python manage.py djstripe_init_customers

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/hero/awes01/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/hero/awes01/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/hero/awes01/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/hero/awes01/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/hero/awes01/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djstripe/management/commands/djstripe_init_customers.py", line 15, in handle
    for subscriber in get_subscriber_model().objects.filter(customer__isnull=True):
  File "/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/hero/awes01/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 141, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/hero/awes01/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 966, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/hero/awes01/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 265, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/hero/awes01/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 700, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/hero/awes01/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 786, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/hero/awes01/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/hero/awes01/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/hero/awes01/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/hero/awes01/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "djstripe_customer" does not exist
LINE 1: ...r"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" LEFT OUTER JOIN "djstripe_...
```

The error

```
for subscriber in get_subscriber_model().objects.filter(customer__isnull=True):
```

referrs to [line 15 of djstripe_init_customers.py](https://github.com/pydanny/dj-stripe/blob/master/djstripe/management/commands/djstripe_init_customers.py)

I don't understand why the normal migration steps are failing (why it expects "djstripe_customer" to have been created before it has been). Grateful for steps I can take to further trouble-shoot. (I'm assuming I've created the gotcha due to dirty uninstall of initial attempt?)

In case relevant:
My auth system is [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

AUTH_USER_MODEL is not explicitly defined in my settings.py file and has been working fine. (I didn't make a custom user model.)

Answer (score 1):

@kavanaugh-development [solved this](https://github.com/pydanny/dj-stripe/issues/210):

To completely remove remnant of the initial install, I had to **remove the relevant djstripe rows from the migrations table**. "If you don't delete those rows, django will ignore the migration commands the second time around."

```
DELETE FROM django_migrations WHERE app = 'djstripe';
```

Once I had done this, a fresh install of dj-stripe worked perfectly as it did the first time round:

I ran `python manage.py migrate`, which

- re-created a few djstripe rows in `django_migrations` table
- also created (empty) tables required for dj-stripe:

  ```
   djstripe_charge
   djstripe_charge_id_seq
   djstripe_currentsubscription
   djstripe_currentsubscription_id_seq
   djstripe_customer
   djstripe_customer_id_seq
   djstripe_event
   djstripe_event_id_seq
   djstripe_eventprocessingexception
   djstripe_eventprocessingexception_id_seq
   djstripe_invoice
   djstripe_invoice_id_seq
   djstripe_invoiceitem
   djstripe_invoiceitem_id_seq
   djstripe_plan
   djstripe_plan_id_seq
   djstripe_transfer
   djstripe_transfer_id_seq
   djstripe_transferchargefee
   djstripe_transferchargefee_id_seq
  ```

So the required tables are ready to be populated by the subsequent commands

(such as `python manage.py djstripe_init_customers`)

*So that's a general (basic) lesson learned about migrations; hope this helps someone.*

Thanks